# How to fill the calendar from an excel file

Tags: best-practices, python, beamerposter, calendar

I am creating a calendar with marked dates of influential personalities births and deaths with one sentence of description like "the death of mr. XY in YEAR". The "input" is an Excel file containing columns [date] [personality] [year]. From the following questions almost all is (really appreciated) bonus, the marked one is The One.

- What package you think would be the best for the purpose? There is no need to make any more room for extra notes. Just one picture and the calendar table itself.
- Would that be possible in `beamerposter`?
- **Is there any possibility not to fill the calendar "manually"?** I have some knowledge of *Python*, so that could be used as well.

*Example of input data:*

```
1.1     Zemřel Jaroslav Ježek              1942
2.1     Narodil se Otakar Hostinský        1847
3.1     
4.1     Narodil se Josef Suk               1874
5.1     
6.1     Narodil se Tomáš Baltazar Janovka  1669
7.1     
8.1     Zemřela Josefína Dušková           1824
9.1     Zemřel Josef Vycpálek              1969
10.1    Narodil se Paul Nettl              1889
11.1    Zemřel Miroslav Raichl             1998
12.1    Zemřel Eduard Haken                1996
13.1    Zemřel František Blažek            1900
14.1        
15.1        
16.1        
17.1        
18.1        
19.1    Zemřel Václav František Červený   1896
20.1        
21.1    Zemřel Pavel Kurfürst             2004
22.1    Narodil se Petr Eben              1929
23.1        
24.1        
25.1    Zemřel Emil Axman                 1949
26.1    Zemřel Miloslav Ištvan            1990
27.1        
28.1    Zemřela Ema Destinnová            1930
29.1        
30.1    Zemřel Karel Boleslav Jirák       1972
31.1
```

*Desired layout:*

[image]

Comment: If you convert the excel file to a .csv file, then you can import all the data and build a table from it, or even a graphic picture. Then all there is to do is make it look good, unless you want something bare.

Comment: Please, could you be a little more specific? Or share a link or something... I've never done this. Thanks!

Comment: You said that your Excel file contains 3 columns. I suppose it's not such a long list, so you could post it here (using the code formatting), exactly like that, in columns, like: `date, personality, year` and then a new line with the next set of data. Don't forget the commas. :) Given that info, it's easy to compile that into what you need.

Comment: Also, I was thinking it'd be helpful if you could create a mock-up version of a day in your calendar. I mean, an example of how you want a single day box to appear in this calendar. I suppose you don't want the number only, and rather some white space to write text in it?

Comment: OK, thanks! Done. Don't mind the Czech.